# Django: How to deal with compute intensive model

Tags: python, pandas, performance, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and using it for a side project and am facing some efficiency issues as detailed below:

The Django app will show each logged-in user their respective data. The basic app works fine and **models.py** and **views.py** look as follows:

**models.py**:

```
class UserDataParser:
    """ 
        Read data into a pandas DataFrame and manipulate it as needed. This contains
        the master DataFrame which is later filtered as required by different users.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.processParsedData()

    ...
    def processParsedData(self):
        ...
        ...
```

**views.py**:

```
from .models import UserDataParser

def welcome_page(request):
    parser = UserDataParser()

    # do stuff with parser

    return render(request, 'user_page.html', context={'data': parser.get_some_data(request.user)})
```

My issue is: `UserDataParser` is a bit compute intensive as it reads some data on disk (< 100MB) and then does some pre-processing (groupBy, filtering etc). Therefore, when `welcome_page` is called to render the user's page, the web-page takes a few minutes to load, since the instantiated model first reads the data and does its computations before returning the required data.

My question is: is there a more efficient/better way of structuring my code such that data is computed before hand on the server-side? Is my approach right or am I missing something very fundamental?

Main goal is to render the user requested pages faster.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: It kinda depends on when/how the user data changes.  If the data has to be very up to date then the best you can do is provide some sort of progress bar for the user.  However, if the data can be processed ahead of time then you should look into Celery (or some other async task library) and start processing the data whenever the data changes.

Comment: @FiddleStix: Thanks.